# Shrine upload_options for checksum_algorithm giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, shrine

I'm new to S3 and Shrine, and I'm working with a Shrine uploader in Ruby on Rails to upload files to Amazon S3, which has been in place for a couple of years on this Rails app.

The thing I'm working on has a goal to have S3 generate a checksum when uploading files, and according to these docs for adding a "trailing checksum" the `ChecksumAlgorithm` needs to be used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html

In the ruby SDK docs, it lists `checksum_algorithm` as a param.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method

When I add the param in the Shrine uploader (`plugin :upload_options, { checksum_algorithm: 'SHA256' })` and upload the file, I get the error `ArgumentError: unexpected value at params[:checksum_algorithm]` from `aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb:33:in 'validate!'` https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb#L14.

I've tried different cases, with and without the dash, and anything else I can think of syntax-wise, but no luck.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of aws-sdk-s3? Did you manage to get the upload working using aws-sdk-s3 directly, without Shrine?

Comment: It turns out it is a version problem. I updated the gem and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using an older version of `aws-sdk-s3` and updating the gem solved the problem. Thanks @Janko